# [object][object] json to string using jquery in ajax using api controller

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

***[object Object]***

am getting the following results :`[object][object]`

```
 var returndata;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/AddCreditCard/',
            type: 'post',
            datatype: 'json',

            //contentType: 'application/json',
            //data: $('form').serialize(),
            // var Fail_Card = $('form').valueOf();
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {


                Cust_OrderId = response.Cust_OrderId;
                alert(Cust_OrderId);

                date = response.date;
                alert(date);


                if (response.success == true) {
                    alert(response.success);
                    var obj = JSON.stringify(response);
                    var objf = JSON.parse(obj);

                    alert(obj);

                    //alert(response.COLUMNS[0]);
                    alert(objf);
                    alert(response.Cust_OrderId);
                    alert(response);
                    window.location = "/controllername/actionname?Cust_OrderId=" + objf;
                } else {



                    alert(response.success);
                    var obj = JSON.stringify(response);
                    var objf = JSON.parse(obj);


                    alert(obj);


                    window.location = "/controllername/actionname?Cust_OrderId=" + objf;
                    alert(response);
                }
```

my api controller return the following ***`customer id:100032(Cust_OrderId)`***

but `response.Cust_OrderId` is not working .pleas solve this

Comment: What is your response object? Can you write inside of response or controller?

Comment: Can you paste exactly what you're getting back from the server? `customer id:100032(Cust_OrderId)` doesn't seem correct. It's definitely not JSON.

Comment: Use console.log(response), not alert.

Comment: i  getting following the results actionname?Cust_OrderId=[object Object]

Comment: am use this format also console.log(response); , but again coming for [object][object]

Comment: try this, console.log(Cust_OrderId);

Comment: {"order_id":"100032"}

am getting the following results  :"{\"order_id\":\"100032\"}"

Comment: do you want to use order_id value?

Comment: ReferenceError: Cust_OrderId is not defined
 

console.log(Cust_OrderId); yes

Comment: is it {\"order_id\":\"100032\"} value, result's value?

Comment: yes am getting this result using   var obj = JSON.stringify(response);

Comment: yes, i need only action?Cust_OrderId=100032,

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to order_id in result. Below this code:

```
var obj = response; // Json.stringify is unnecessary
var Cust_OrderId = obj.order_id; //this is give value
```

Comment: Above mention format is working fine 100032, but window.location = "/CreditTest/ConfirmationSuccess?Cust_OrderId=" + Cust_OrderId; is getting [object][object] please me solve this

Comment: i need to pass 3 values , how is it?

Comment: Its working for me. thank you so much. were to accept ur answer

Comment: Near to zero, the left

Comment: Hi i need to pass one variable am getting all the results for example: window.location = "/controllername/actionname?Cust_OrderId=" + Cust_OrderId ; i need the following results like :cust_orderId:---,accountno:----, balance:---,  var obj = response; // Json.stringify is unnecessary
                    var Cust_OrderId = obj.order_id;